# command to get metadata for all the tables of oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

can anyone please help me with SQL Developer command to get the information about number of rows in a tables, number of columns in each table and most current updated day for every table of a particular schema?

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of rows and the day of the latest SCN for each table of the the schema `TEST`:

```
CREATE TYPE TEST.stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  t_sql TEST.stringlist;
  v_sql CLOB;
  v_scn NUMBER;
  v_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST';
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(SCN)
  INTO   v_scn
  FROM   sys.smon_scn_time;

  SELECT 'SELECT ''' || TABLE_NAME || ''' AS table_name, '
                 || 'TRUNC( MAX( CASE WHEN ORA_ROWSCN >= ' || v_scn || ' THEN SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP( ORA_ROWSCN ) END ) ) AS last_update_day, '
                 || 'COUNT(*) AS num_rows '
         || 'FROM ' || v_owner || '.' || table_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_sql
  FROM   ALL_TABLES
  WHERE  OWNER = v_owner;

  v_sql := t_sql(1);
  FOR i IN 2 .. t_sql.COUNT LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL ' || t_sql(i);
  END LOOP;

  OPEN :cur FOR v_sql;  
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

To get the number of columns for each table of the schema `TEST`:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COUNT(*) AS num_columns
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  OWNER = 'TEST'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```